# Simplifying Ruby control flow when defining variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, control-flow

I'm defining three variables on a Rails app's page:

```
  if current_user
    if Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id, :direction => 0).count > 0
      active = ' upactive'
    elsif Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id, :direction => 1).count > 0
      active = ' downactive'
    end
  end

  unless Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 0).count[post.id] == nil
    upvotes = Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 0).count[post.id]
  else
    upvotes = 0
  end

  unless Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 1).count[post.id] == nil
    downvotes = Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 1).count[post.id]
  else
    downvotes = 0
  end
```

I notice there is quite a bit of repeated code in the if and unless statements. How can I write three variable declarations that equal the ones above, making sure the variable is always `0` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the conditional assignment operator here to help reduce code. For example:

```
if current_user
  if Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id, :direction => 0).count > 0
    active = ' upactive'
  elsif Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id, :direction => 1).count > 0
    active = ' downactive'
  end
end

upvotes = Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 0).count[post.id] || 0
downvotes = Vote.group(:post_id).where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :direction => 1).count[post.id] || 0
```

The conditional assignment operator essentially says if the first portion evaluates to nil, use the right side as the default value.

Comment: +1 for the refactoring of upvotes and down votes. I was just working on that too. It should be faster because of the reduction of DB hits. I'm also wondering whether the `elseif` should just be `else`, because there's a potential logic hole allowing `active` to be undefined if both `Vote` queries `count == 0`.

Comment: I mostly left the active variable alone because I don't have enough information in context, but I agree there could be logic holes there. For example, if the current user can only have one vote on a post, then that logic could be simplified by using something like Vote.first(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id) and then evaluating the direction in Ruby. But since I don't know much about the app, I left it alone. :)

Comment: Heh, glad it's not my system to maintain. :-)

Comment: I meant Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => post.id).first. That one should actually work.